# Storing the connection id of a specific client in SignalR hub

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

Below you can see a simplified version of my SignalR self hosted hub on a windows service:

```
public static class SubscriptionHandler
{
    public static int PriceFeedMembersCount = 0;
}

public class PriceHub : Hub
{
    public Task SubscribeToPriceFeed()
    {
        IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<PriceHub>();
        if (SubscriptionHandler.PriceFeedMembersCount == 0)
        {
            context.Clients.All.updatePriceSubscriptionStatus(true);
        }
        SubscriptionHandler.PriceFeedMembersCount++;
        return context.Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, "PriceFeed");
    }

    public Task UnsubscribeFromPriceFeed()
    {
        IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<PriceHub>();
        SubscriptionHandler.PriceFeedMembersCount--;
        if (SubscriptionHandler.PriceFeedMembersCount == 0)
        {
            context.Clients.All.updatePriceSubscriptionStatus(false);
        }
        return context.Groups.Remove(Context.ConnectionId, "PriceFeed");
    }

    public void NotifySubscribers(Price price)
    {
        IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<PriceHub>();
        context.Clients.Group("PriceFeed").updatePrice(price);
    }
}
```

And I have two types of clients for that hub: One of them is web applications and the other one is windows services. Here you can see a demo implementation for my windows service as a signalr client:

```
public partial class WinSer45 : ServiceBase
{
    private HubConnection hubConnection;
    private IHubProxy priceProxy;
    private Timer timer = new Timer();
    private bool hasSubscribers = false;

    public WinSer45()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        timer.Interval = 1000; // saniyede bir
        timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
        timer.Enabled = true;

        hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:8080/signalr", useDefaultUrl: false);
        priceProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("PriceHub");
        hubConnection.Start().Wait();
        priceProxy.On<bool>("UpdatePriceSubscriptionStatus", hasSubscribers =>
        {
            this.hasSubscribers = hasSubscribers;
        });
    }

    void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {   
        if (hasSubscribers)
        {
            TestPrice testPrice = new TestPrice() { Id = 1, Buy = 1.2345, Sell = 9.8765, Symbol = "EURUSD" };
            priceProxy.Invoke("NotifySubscribers", testPrice).Wait();    
        }
    }   

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
    }
}
```

As you see I use the **hasSubscribers** flag to minimize the messages between hub and clients. And hasSubscribers flag is changed by **SubscribeToPriceFeed**  and **UnsubscribeFromPriceFeed** methods.

If you look carefully you see the line below in SubscribeToPriceFeed:

> context.Clients.All.updatePriceSubscriptionStatus(true);

I don't want to send the message to all clients but my client windows service. How can I store the connection Id of a specific client in my hub? If I can do that, I know I can send message to a specific connectionId as in the line below:

> context.Clients.Client(connectionId).updatePriceSubscriptionStatus(true);

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pass source during connection

like this

```
hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:8080/signalr","source=windows",useDefaultUrl: false);
```

**HUB**

```
public override Task OnConnected()
{
    var source= Context.QueryString['source'];
    return base.OnConnected();
}
```

create a class which will hold the user with source

```
public class user {
  public string ConnectionID {set;get;}
  public string Source {set;get;}
}
```

declare a list in the hub

```
List<user> userList=new List<user>();
```

Then push the user during OnConnected

```
public override Task OnConnected()
{
    var us=new user();
    us.Source = Context.QueryString['source'];
    us.ConnectionID=Context.ConnectionId;
    userList.Add(us);
    return base.OnConnected();
}
```

and during broadcast just filter it by source

```
var windowsUser=userList.Where(o=>o.Source == "windows").ToList(); // you'll get the windows user list
```

Comment: Remember: 
public override Task OnReconnected() {
            return base.OnConnected();
        }